# Conversion from 2d (.dwg) to 3d with VectorWorks2015

Tags: 3d, 2d, dwg

I'm looking to import a 2d drawing (.dwg) where all the 3 dimensions (+ a perspective) of an object are drawn. There are no lines that bonds the pieces of the views.
Is there a way to obtain automatically a 3d model from this drawing with VectorWorks 2015? Or am I supposed to make it by my own?
(the Extrude doesn't work properly)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find an automatic way to do this.

If the extrude does not work, it's probably because the object is not of the proper type. You can try to convert it to polygon prior export. modify > convert.
If it's a group, you need to ungroup it first. (ungroup).
If it's a symbol, you need to convert it to group first (convert to group) then, ungroup it.

Comment: apologies, but I can't try anymore to solve this... however i'll leave the question open, hoping your answer (or the one from somebody else) will be usefull for someone